# Determining an unbiased Estimator $T$ using $S$

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to construct an estimator $T$ using $S$, which is an unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{a}$.

We are given the following:

$S = \sum_{i=1}^n X^3_i$

$E[X^3] = \frac{1}{3a}$

Obviously it follows that $E[S] = \frac{n}{3a}$.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just define your estimator to be

$$
T= \frac{3S}{n},
$$

then $E(T)= \frac{3}{n} E(S)= \frac{3}{n} \frac{n}{3a} = \frac{1}{a}$.